# How to change the name of the typscript source file generated using ttypescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, code-generation

I have created a typescript interface in file Demo.ts which has following code

```
export inteface Demo{
}
```

Now I am trying to generate implementation of Demo interface that is DemoImpl using [ttypescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript) library.

The transformation code is able to generate implementation propely, but the file in which the implementation code is getting generated is Demo.js.

But then I am facing below error

> error TS2693: 'Demo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
> value here. When Demo.js and Demo.ts are in same folder

I would like to create both source and generated file in same folder.

So I want the generated file name to be DemoImpl.js. But I don't find any way to do this using ttypescript library.

Can somebody please help me with this?